# Template file not loading

Tags: templates

I added a new page in this hierarchy:
`CRM/Mymodule/Page/subdir/MyPage.php`
and added a template file at
`templates/CRM/Mymodule/subdir/MyPage.tpl`.

But when I run *MyPage.php*, I get a blank page. Template contents aren't displayed. Adding *smartyDebug=1* to the URL doesn't trigger a popup either. Strangely though, if I *var_dump* a variable, I can see the page with menu bar, page title and the variable info. So *MyPage.php* is being invoked.

Is it that pages don't support subdirectories? I tried adding the template file using *Region*. That didn't work either.

**UPDATE**:

I created a page and a corresponding template on `CRM/Mymodule/Page/MyPage.php` and `templates/CRM/Mymodule/MyPage.tpl` respectively and manually wrote a route. It didn't work. I then used civix to generate the same page and template. It worked. So, is it compulsory that we create using `civix`? But I had manually created the form and it had worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say best to stick with where Civix (aka Tim) says it should go! (i.e. no subdirs) - and note that Civix can help you create the page:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addabasicwebpage

To generate a Page:

```
me@civisys:/home/me$ cd /var/www/extensions/com.example.myextension
me@civisys:/var/www/extensions/com.example.myextension$ civix generate:page --help
Usage:
 generate:page className webPath

Arguments:
 className  Page class name (eg "MyPage")
 webPath    The path which maps to this page (eg "civicrm/my-page")

me@civisys:/var/www/extensions/com.example.myextension$ civix generate:page Greeter civicrm/greeter
Write /var/www/extensions/com.example.myextension/xml/Menu/myextension.xml
Write /var/www/extensions/com.example.myextension/CRM/Myextension/Page/Greeter.php
Write /var/www/extensions/com.example.myextension/templates/CRM/Myextension/Page/Greeter.tpl
```

Comment: @karing-semper- Is it possible to create subdirs at all? I feel creating subdirs makes it more clean and more readable. Also can you please see the update?

Comment: I really don't think subdirs are necessary as essentially these Pages are already in subdirectories by extension. When you create the Pages manually - don't forget the class name: example in our iATSAdmin.php: class CRM_iATS_Page_iATSAdmin extends CRM_Core_Page {

Comment: Civix is not compulsory - but it adds all you need in one command line - I still tend to use it - just b/c it's faster than generating pages (php and tpl) and adding in the class by hand

Comment: It's indeed faster. I just figured the template wasn't loading because I had omitted `parent::run()` on the `run()` method. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have set environment to Development and Disabled asset cache at at/civicrm/admin/setting/debug?reset=1
It worked for me.